# Jupyter notebook progress bar issue in TensorFlow method

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers

When using `TFAutoModel.from_pretrained()` the following error is returned

```py
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/contracts/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/notebook.py in status_printer(_, total, desc, ncols)
    110         # Prepare IPython progress bar
    111         if IProgress is None:  # #187 #451 #558 #872
--> 112             raise ImportError(
    113                 "IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets."
    114                 " See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable"

ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
```

I've followed these links, manually installed tqdm, IProgress, and ipywidgets. For whatever reason, this TensorFlow object method is unable to execute. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyter_client
```

According to this thread: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2527, seems to have solved the problem to many people. Also do not forget to restart the jupyter kernel each time you try a new solution in order to determine what actually worked.